# Error while starting Jupyter notebook from terminal on Mac OS

Tags: python3, jupyter-notebook, ipython

I've been fiddling with my anaconda, jupyter, IPython installations, and I honestly don't know how I ended up with this error. Can anyone help me resolve this so I can get back to running jupyter notebooks with Python 3.x?

```
[C 17:01:34.358 NotebookApp] Bad config encountered during initialization:
[C 17:01:34.359 NotebookApp] The 'contents_manager_class' trait of <notebook.notebookapp.NotebookApp object at 0x1016caa90> instance must be a type, but 'jupytext.TextFileContentsManager' could not be imported
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The issue was a bad config file that got in there somehow. This answer https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/274 helped me resolve the problem. I had to go to the folder path that was returned when I ran the following command

```
jupyter --config-dir
```

I removed all files in this folder and ran

```
jupyter notebook
```

and this opened the jupyter notebook normally.

Comment: This worked well, Thanks Abel!!

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not solve the issue for me

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the problem on Linux by installed jupytext:

```
pip install jupytext
```

Comment: this solved my problem.